# Firebase :- Pending Deep-link is not working

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I have checked in official document as well in other sites but Pending deeplink URL is not calling any app delegate function. if app is installed everything is working fine but in case of installation, I couldn't able to get deeplink URL.

Comment: let me know if someone has solved it before

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned in the Official guide from Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive)

I had faced the issue of the app not opening before, later I came to know that the deep linking URL is parsed differently now.

Comment: Thanks fro ur reply, I am getting the call in case of installed app but not when app is getting installed first time.